# Chrome for iOS keeps loggin out of reddit.com

Tags: ios, google-chrome, login

Google Chrome for iOS refuses to remember my login session once closed, nor does it remember my username or password.

Other websites (google.com) autologin and stay logged in just fine in Chrome for iOS, and other browsers (Chrome desktop, Safari iOS) have no trouble with Reddit.

- Latest Chrome for iOS
- iOS 7
- 2013 iPad Mini, non-Retina

Anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in to reddit with HTTPS at [pay.reddit.com](http://pay.reddit.com)

I can't say for sure if this will work, but at least it's something to try.

pay.reddit.com is HTTPS, not HTTP. Explanation: http://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/1y9543/ive_seen_httpspayredditcomr_a_few_times_what/